# Jquery UI 1.10.4 Autocomplete causes an error "Cannot read property Value of Undefined" on selection of item

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC5 application ,with Angular JS and Bootstrap 3

Jquery 1.10.2 and JQuery UI is 1.10.4

Autocomplete directive in angular

For the Auto complete,i am getting the source by making a call to the controller and returning a JSON response

So the autocomplete is rendering the data without any issues,However when I select an option which is auto populated,I am getting an error in the browser as

" Uncaught Type Error : Cannot read property value of undefined in line 2295 on Jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"

Did anyone see this error before

Here is my some sample code

```
   <<Autocompletedirective object>> .data('ui-autocomplete')
   ._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                   return $('<li></li>')
                  .data('ui-autocomplete-item', item)
                  .append('<a>' + item.FirstName+ '-' + item.LastName+ '</a>')
                  .appendTo(ul);
                    };
```

Any idea why we are getting this error?

Comment: just guessing you need to add an LI to append to UL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
              .data('ui-autocomplete')
              ._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
               return $('<li>')
              .append('<a>' + item.FirstName+ '-' + item.LastName+ '</a>')
              .appendTo(ul);
                };
```

and be sure that the data returned has the property FirstName and LastName.